# ServiceStack.Ormlite Postgres case insensitive queries

Tags: postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am looking to cleanly implement a mechanism to override all where clauses that compare strings to do the following

[Column].Value.ToLower() == SqlParam.ToLower()

effectively overcoming the case sensitivity of Postgres.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807276/how-to-make-my-postgresql-database-use-a-case-insensitive-collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrmLite's [INamingStrategy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/INamingStrategy.cs) allows you to customize how Schemas, Tables and Columns are named and OrmLite's PostgreSQL Provider is already configured to use the [PostgreSqlNamingStrategy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL/PostgreSqlNamingStrategy.cs) which converts or .NET's **PascalCase** names to PostgreSQL-friendly **snake_case**.