# How to ignore case sensitive rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I know this question may duplicate but i really got confused since I'm new to PostgreSQL. I'm trying to store emails which must not be case sensitive. For example `Johndoe@gmail.com` must be identical with `JoHnDoE@gmail.com` in PostgreSQL but i can't find any solution. I know about `lower()` function, But i don't want use it.

Any solution? Or this is not possible at all in PostgreSQL ? I'm using pgAdmin 4

Comment: "*But i don't want use it*" - why? Please expand on your use case if you're throwing out perfectly fine options for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Non deterministic collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC) (only PostgreSQL version >= 12):

From https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101294/how-to-create-postgres-db-with-case-insensitive-collation :

```sql
CREATE COLLATION ndcoll (provider = icu, locale = 'und', deterministic = false);
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false);
CREATE COLLATION ignore_accents (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level1-kc-true', deterministic = false);
```

#### Edit

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101567/2928168 :

```sql
    CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (
      provider = icu,
      locale = 'und-u-ks-level2',
      deterministic = false
    );

    CREATE TABLE names(
      first_name text,
      /* Example collation used in schema directly */
      last_name text COLLATE "case_insensitive",
    );

    insert into names values
      ('Anton','Egger'),
      ('Berta','egger'),
      ('Conrad','Egger');

    select * from names
      order by
        last_name,
        /* Example collation used only in some query */
        first_name collate case_insensitive;
```

Comment: But how to enable it for specific column? like as i said, "email" field. Explain please

Comment: Added example .

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate

Comment: How to combine both of them (unaccent + case insensitive) and which index to use for both sided LIKE queries, please? thanks!

Comment: @Lunack Your question is different than the posted here, as the author wanted to declare the field this way, not only use it in a comparison. You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-string.html) in both members of the comparison.

Comment: I don't want use function at all but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ILIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) operator (or its equivalent `~~*` for `ILIKE` and `!~~*` for `NOT ILIKE`).

Comment: I don't want use function at all but thanks

Comment: This is not a function.

Comment: If you post an example of the query you are trying to use, I can make an example with it.

Comment: Yes but i mean " Is there any data type like MySQL " which ignore case sensitive ?

Comment: Ahhh, you mean how to declare a field as case insensitive?

Comment: Yeaaaaah that's what i mean but because i'm confused and it's late here...How to do it?

Comment: @AqilHex there is: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html