# PostgreSQL case-insensitive and accent-insensitive search

Tags: postgresql, search, indexing

I have a data table and I would like to filter the columns. For example, to search for a user by his fullname.

However, I would like to allow the user to enter the search phrase case-independent and accents-independent.

So I have checked these (and more) sources and questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216
- [How to ignore case sensitive rows in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483444/how-to-ignore-case-sensitive-rows-in-postgresql/)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC

I thought the nondeterministic collations might finally be the right way how to achieve that, but unfortunately I don't know how:

- combine case_insensitive and ignore_accents into one collation
- how to allow searching only by substring in such a WHERE (e.g., find "Jóhn Doe" only by the string "joh") as nondeterministic collations do not support LIKE or regular expressions
- which index to use

I would be very grateful for any advice on how to finally deal with this type of problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating case and accent insensitive ICU collations is pretty simple:

```
CREATE COLLATION english_ci_ai (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE,
   LOCALE = "en-US-u-ks-level1"
);
```

Or, equivalently (that syntax also works wil old ICU versions:

```
CREATE COLLATION english_ci_ai (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   DETERMINISTIC = FALSE,
   LOCALE = "en-US@colStrength=primary"
);
```

See [the ICU documentation](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-13.html) for details and [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/icu-collations-against-glibc-2-28-data-corruption/) for a detailed discussion.

But your problem is that you want substring search. So you should create a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;

CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin (unaccent(doc) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then you can search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE unaccent(doc) ILIKE unaccent('%joh%');
```

Note that you have to force a minimal length of 4 or so on the search string if you want that to be efficient.

Comment: Thank you, your article helped me to understand how creating a custom ICU collation works. However, unfortunately my problem with not being able to search with a non-deterministic ICU according to a portion of the string persists.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I thought I'd have to stick with this unaccent solution. I just have to create an IMMUTABLE version of unaccent as mentioned in my first link. Thank you!