How to use EXCEPT operator in PostgresSQL with case insensitivity?
I have two tables, Table_1 and Table_2. I want to compare one of the columns between the tables and have an output of the difference.
Specifically, I need to know which entries (of a column) of Table_1 are not present in table 2. I am using the EXCEPT operator but the numbers aren't correct so I'd like to know how to make it case insensitive.
Here is my basic approach (without the case insensitive stuff):
SELECT "Address" FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT "People Address" FROM Table_2

So I thought I'd use:
SELECT "Address" FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT "People Address" FROM Table_2

To make it case insensitive, I've tried:
SELECT "Address" COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT "People Address" COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM Table_2

With the approoach above, I am getting the following error:
db query error: pq: collation "Latin1_General_CI_AS" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist. 

How can I include case insensitivity? This is in PostgresSQL

COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS is MS SQL Server syntax. Why not something like UPPER(Address)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807276/how-to-make-my-postgresql-database-use-a-case-insensitive-collation/59101567#59101567

The COLLATE clause us ISO/ANSI SQL. However, each dbms has its own naming of collations

@Sergey like this? SELECT UPPER(Address) ?

Exactly. If you want you can also add TRIM

You can create a case insensitive collation:
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false);

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html
And use it as expected:
SELECT "Address" COLLATE case_insensitive FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT "People Address" COLLATE case_insensitive FROM Table_2

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/lFOBATce

That's far the best answer because this query returns the rows as they are and doesn't change their case.

COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS is MS SQL server syntax. So I ended up using the UPPER keyword like this:
SELECT UPPER("Address") FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT UPPER("People Address") FROM Table_2

Thanks to the comments posted in the question by @sergey

The COLLATE clause is ANSI/ISO SQL. https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ can be used to verify SQL standard compliance.

The error you specified in PostgreSQL is due to the fact that the Latin1_General_CI_AS statement specific to SQL Server is not recognized in PostgreSQL. To correct this error, you can use the LOWER or UPPER functions to make a case-insensitive comparison in PostgreSQL.
Below I show you how you can write a query to compare address columns and find case-insensitive differences:
SELECT LOWER("Address") AS Address FROM Table_1
EXCEPT
SELECT LOWER("People Address") AS Address FROM Table_2;
  

